# Pegar cadastro de empresa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, asp.net-core

sou nova em c#, gostaria da ajuda para pegar e empresa registrada pelo usuario X, o que preciso é a função *PegarEmpresaLogado*

FuncionariosController

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Novo funcionario");
        var empresa = await _empresaRepositorio.PegarEmpresaLogado(usuarioID);
        var funcionario = new Funcionario {EmpresaId = empresa.EmpresaId };
        return View(funcionario);
    }
```

Models.Empresa

```
public class Empresa
{
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    ............

    public string UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Funcionario> Funcionarios { get; set; }
}
```

Models.Funcionario

```
public class Funcionario
{
    public int FuncId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Use menos caracteres")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    ...........
    public string Demissao { get; set; }

    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: você precisa pegar o usuário logado (que está cadastrando)? ou a empresa que ele ta cadastrando? ou a empresa que esse usuário que está cadastrando pertence?